# Can't pass custom object, ejb remote interface and JPA, Netbeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, serialization, jpa, netbeans, glassfish-3

I'm using Netbeans 7, JEE project with application client, stateless ejb with remote interface, and JPA entity clasess made from sql script.

Interfaces are in separate library project which is referenced in ejb and client project.

And the problem is the remote method that use **custom interface object made from entity class cannot be returned**. Serialized probably.

Remote methods that use standard types work properly.

You can look exceptions at the error code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.RemoteException: CORBA NO_IMPLEMENT 1398079489 Maybe;
```

and this one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: entity_klase.Varalica (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

I'm suspecting that **interface and entity class aren't matching** exactly so object can't be reconstructed at client side.

**This info should be enough, if you need more relevant details I attached bellow entity class, interface from that class, remote interface, ejb implementing function, and complete error log.**

So here is entity class:

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package entity_klase;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author ime1
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "VARALICA")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findAll", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findById", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findByNaziv", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.naziv = :naziv"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findBySlika", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.slika = :slika"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findByLager", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.lager = :lager"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findByCena", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.cena = :cena"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findByVelicina", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.velicina = :velicina"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findByBoja", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.boja = :boja"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findByOpis", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.opis = :opis"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findByAkcijaTrajanje", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.akcijaTrajanje = :akcijaTrajanje"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findByAkcijaProcenat", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.akcijaProcenat = :akcijaProcenat"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findByTipVaralice", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.tipVaralice = :tipVaralice"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Varalica.findByPopust", query = "SELECT v FROM Varalica v WHERE v.popust = :popust")})
public class Varalica implements VaralicaRemote, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "NAZIV")
    private String naziv;
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "SLIKA")
    private String slika;
    @Column(name = "LAGER")
    private Integer lager;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "CENA")
    private Double cena;
    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "VELICINA")
    private String velicina;
    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "BOJA")
    private String boja;
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "OPIS")
    private String opis;
    @Column(name = "AKCIJA_TRAJANJE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date akcijaTrajanje;
    @Column(name = "AKCIJA_PROCENAT")
    private Integer akcijaProcenat;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
    @Column(name = "TIP_VARALICE")
    private String tipVaralice;
    @Column(name = "POPUST")
    private Integer popust;

    public Varalica() {
    }

    public Varalica(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Varalica(Integer id, String tipVaralice) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tipVaralice = tipVaralice;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNaziv() {
        return naziv;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNaziv(String naziv) {
        this.naziv = naziv;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSlika() {
        return slika;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSlika(String slika) {
        this.slika = slika;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getLager() {
        return lager;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLager(Integer lager) {
        this.lager = lager;
    }

    @Override
    public Double getCena() {
        return cena;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCena(Double cena) {
        this.cena = cena;
    }

    @Override
    public String getVelicina() {
        return velicina;
    }

    @Override
    public void setVelicina(String velicina) {
        this.velicina = velicina;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBoja() {
        return boja;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBoja(String boja) {
        this.boja = boja;
    }

    @Override
    public String getOpis() {
        return opis;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOpis(String opis) {
        this.opis = opis;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getAkcijaTrajanje() {
        return akcijaTrajanje;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAkcijaTrajanje(Date akcijaTrajanje) {
        this.akcijaTrajanje = akcijaTrajanje;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getAkcijaProcenat() {
        return akcijaProcenat;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAkcijaProcenat(Integer akcijaProcenat) {
        this.akcijaProcenat = akcijaProcenat;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTipVaralice() {
        return tipVaralice;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTipVaralice(String tipVaralice) {
        this.tipVaralice = tipVaralice;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getPopust() {
        return popust;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPopust(Integer popust) {
        this.popust = popust;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Varalica)) {
            return false;
        }
        Varalica other = (Varalica) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entity_klase.Varalica[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

And here is interface from that class in library project:

```
    package entity_klase;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
//import javax.persistence.*;
//import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
//import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
//import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author ime1
 */


public interface VaralicaRemote extends Serializable {

    public  Integer getId();

    public  void setId(Integer id);

    public  String getNaziv();

    public  void setNaziv(String naziv);

    public  String getSlika();

    public  void setSlika(String slika);

    public  Integer getLager();

    public  void setLager(Integer lager);

    public  Double getCena();

    public  void setCena(Double cena);

    public  String getVelicina();

    public  void setVelicina(String velicina);

    public  String getBoja();

    public  void setBoja(String boja);

    public  String getOpis();

    public  void setOpis(String opis);

    public  Date getAkcijaTrajanje();

    public  void setAkcijaTrajanje(Date akcijaTrajanje);

    public  Integer getAkcijaProcenat();

    public  void setAkcijaProcenat(Integer akcijaProcenat);

    public  String getTipVaralice();

    public  void setTipVaralice(String tipVaralice);

    public  Integer getPopust();

    public  void setPopust(Integer popust);

    @Override
    public  int hashCode();

    @Override
    public  boolean equals(Object object);

    @Override
    public  String toString();


}
```

And here is stateles bean remote interface:

```
package za_admin;

import entity_klase.VaralicaRemote;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

/**
 *
 * @author ime1
 */
@Remote
public interface ZaAdminSessionBeanRemote {

    List<String> getGrupe();



    List<String> getNaziviProizvodaGrupe(String grupa);

    VaralicaRemote getVaralica(String naziv);//THIS METHOD WONT WORK

}
```

And here is method bean implementation which is working, I debugged it, snaps at return statement:

```
@Override
public VaralicaRemote getVaralica(String naziv) {

 VaralicaRemote varalica = null;

    try {

        Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT OBJECT(v) FROM Varalica v WHERE v.naziv = :naziv");
        q1.setParameter("naziv", naziv);         
        varalica = (VaralicaRemote) q1.getSingleResult();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
   return varalica;//HERE IT SNAPS
}
```

And here is persistance.xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Projekat-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/security</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And here is error log:

```
    init:
JavaLibraryZaRemote1.init:
Deleting: E:\Documents and Settings\ime1\Desktop\Projekat1\Projekat\JavaLibraryZaRemote1\build\built-jar.properties
JavaLibraryZaRemote1.deps-jar:
Updating property file: E:\Documents and Settings\ime1\Desktop\Projekat1\Projekat\JavaLibraryZaRemote1\build\built-jar.properties
JavaLibraryZaRemote1.compile:
JavaLibraryZaRemote1.jar:
deps-jar:
compile:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
Building jar: E:\Documents and Settings\ime1\Desktop\Projekat1\Admin\dist\Admin.jar
dist:
pre-run-deploy:
Distributing E:\Documents and Settings\ime1\Desktop\Projekat1\Admin\dist\Admin.jar to [GlassFish Server 3.1.2]
post-run-deploy:
run-deploy:
Copying 1 file to E:\Documents and Settings\ime1\Desktop\Projekat1\Admin\dist
Copying 2 files to E:\Documents and Settings\ime1\Desktop\Projekat1\Admin\dist\AdminClient
Warning: E:\Documents and Settings\ime1\Desktop\Projekat1\Admin\dist\gfdeploy\Admin does not exist.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.RemoteException: CORBA NO_IMPLEMENT 1398079489 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: WARNING: IOP01000001: Missing local value implementation  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy134.missingLocalValueImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseImplBase._invoke(_CodeBaseImplBase.java:99)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: entity_klase.Varalica (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:375)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:135)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClassM(JDKBridge.java:319)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClass(JDKBridge.java:228)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.loadClass(Util.java:640)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.RepositoryId.getClassFromType(RepositoryId.java:577)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.getClassFromType(ValueHandlerImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:105)
    ... 12 more

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at za_admin._ZaAdminSessionBeanRemote_Wrapper.getVaralica(za_admin/_ZaAdminSessionBeanRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at admin.AdminJFrame.jList2MouseReleased(AdminJFrame.java:448)
    at admin.AdminJFrame.access$400(AdminJFrame.java:44)
    at admin.AdminJFrame$7.mouseReleased(AdminJFrame.java:291)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:273)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6134)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5899)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2023)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4501)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2081)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4331)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4301)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3965)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3895)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2067)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2458)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4331)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: CORBA NO_IMPLEMENT 1398079489 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: WARNING: IOP01000001: Missing local value implementation  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy134.missingLocalValueImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseImplBase._invoke(_CodeBaseImplBase.java:99)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: entity_klase.Varalica (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:375)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:135)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClassM(JDKBridge.java:319)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClass(JDKBridge.java:228)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.loadClass(Util.java:640)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.RepositoryId.getClassFromType(RepositoryId.java:577)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.getClassFromType(ValueHandlerImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:105)
    ... 12 more

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:311)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at za_admin.__ZaAdminSessionBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.getVaralica(za_admin/__ZaAdminSessionBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: WARNING: IOP01000001: Missing local value implementation  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy134.missingLocalValueImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseImplBase._invoke(_CodeBaseImplBase.java:99)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: entity_klase.Varalica (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:375)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:135)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClassM(JDKBridge.java:319)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.JDKBridge.loadClass(JDKBridge.java:228)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.loadClass(Util.java:640)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.RepositoryId.getClassFromType(RepositoryId.java:577)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.getClassFromType(ValueHandlerImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.FVDCodeBaseImpl.implementation(FVDCodeBaseImpl.java:105)
    ... 12 more

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.getSystemException(MessageBase.java:900)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.ReplyMessage_1_2.getSystemException(ReplyMessage_1_2.java:131)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.getSystemExceptionReply(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:637)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.processResponse(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:499)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:273)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(ObjectImpl.java:457)
    at com.sun.org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseStub.implementation(_CodeBaseStub.java:63)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CachedCodeBase.implementation(CachedCodeBase.java:119)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.getClassFromString(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:2292)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1095)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:384)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:203)
    ... 28 more
run-single:
```

Comment: That's one heck of a wall of code and other artefacts. Maybe you could reduce this to a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/), that way you'll probably get more folks willing to help out. Also see: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: You can look at error log, and if you want to know more take look at code that you think  is relevant.

Comment: I'm not even going to attempt to answer this, I'm just providing some friendly moderator advice.

Comment: "I'm not even going to attempt to answer this, I'm just providing some friendly moderator advice."

If you could stop helping me, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need return entity class  Varalica, and use  VaralicaRemote as class remote to cast the methods returned by ejb.